# Android: Cannot center my GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I want to display a grid of buttons 15 buttons, 3 columns and 5 rows.
They should be centered horizontally and vertically with equal spacing between them in the same direction (meaning same space horizontally between all buttons but could have another space vertically as long as the space vertically is the same).

Here is what it looks like now (not at all what I want):
http://sv.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dbgjll&s=8#.U-ELkNbzTFY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/choose_level_grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/wood_background"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:horizontalSpacing="60dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="60dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level1_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:text="@string/level1_btn_text"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level2_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level2_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level3_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level3_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level4_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level4_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level5_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level5_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level6_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level6_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level7_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level7_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level8_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level8_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level9_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level9_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level10_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level10_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level11_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level11_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level12_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level12_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level13_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level13_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level14_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level14_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level15_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button_shape"
        android:padding="@dimen/main_menu_button_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor_on_transparent_brown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/choose_level_text_size"
        android:text="@string/level15_btn_text"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/choose_level_button_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/choose_level_button_width"
    />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center if you use Relative Layout and made a little changes on your code, here is mine:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/choose_level_grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:horizontalSpacing="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="60dp" >
```

After setting this properties at your RelativeLayout and GridLayout, this would be the result:

[image]

Comment: Ty, that worked great. However I also want to space evenly between buttons. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you just need add margin to each button: android:layout_margin="20dp"

Comment: Ty, that works reasonably. But I would like the margin between buttons be the same as between the outer buttons and the to the side of the view if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I got it. My advice is adjust the margin programmatically, as you would probably run this application on different devices with different screen sizes and densities. You just need to ask another question or look for good practices on setting margins programmatically.

Comment: As I helped you to solve your original problem, to center the content of a gridview, could you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: Well the thing is I did this all programmtically from the start but wanted to do it in xml instead. But if I have to do something programmatically then I might as well do all of it. I wanted to change to xml because I was told calculating stuff from the canvas size is bad.

Comment: It seems like the standard way to do a grid would be to have equal space in all directions so i expected gridLayout to do this but it does not seem to be easy to make it do that.